# python how to implement a list into a tree?

Tags: python, data-structures

I have a list of data indicates what direction is going next like:

```
[[0,1,0,0,1],[0,0,1],[0,0],[0,1,1,1,0]]
```

I want to implement this data into a tree structure like:
[image]

The number inside the node is how many people walked on this direction.

I have a Tree class that I write myself like this:

```
class Tree(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = 0
def insert(self,num):
    self.data = self.data + 1
    if num == 0:
        if self.left == None:
            self.left = Tree()
        return self.left
    elif num == 1:
        if self.right == None:
            self.right = Tree()
        return self.right
```

How can I do this? I tried to make it in a recursive way but turns out it's not saving under `root` but `build_tree` which is a variable that I tried to make as the recursive pointer.

```
root = Tree()
for route in data:
    build_tree = root
    for i in range (0,len(route)):
        num = route[i]
        build_tree = build_tree.insert(num)
```

Thanks!

Edit: This code actually works just like Blender said in comment. I think I had something wrong when I implemented it to a more complex code.

Also thanks John La Rooy for the suggestion and Kevin K. for the example!

Comment: Your code works fine, from what I can tell. Why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: You might be able to simplify the code some more by using a 2 element list `self.children` instead of left and right. ie `self.children[0]` and `self.children[1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making a separate class for the node like so

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

Then in your `Tree` class initialize `self.root` and declare your functions with recursion within `Tree`

Edit: [Here](https://github.com/kkirchhoff01/MiscScripts/blob/master/binary_tree.py) is an example.